# Project a parabolic curve to straight lines.

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, geometric-construction

I am working with Voronoi Diagrams and I'm given a parabolic curve that is described through four *parameters*:

- A start point, say $P_0(x_0,y_0)$.
- An end point, say $P_1(x_1,y_1)$.
- A focus point, say $F(x_f,y_f)$.
- And a directrix line $l$, say from point $L_0$ to $L_1$.

[image]

Instead of calculating the parabola points (as in the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#In_a_cartesian_coordinate_system)), I'd like to find a third point, let's say $C$, that creates two straight lines (e.g. horizontal and vertical) between $P_0$ and $P_1$, such that it "follows" the curve. For example, for the following image, if $P_0 = (3,3)$  and $P_1 = (5,1)$, then I want to find $C = (3,1)$.

I was looking into [Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve), but it does not seem to fulfill my needs. The control point seems to depend on the curvature of the parabola, thus it might not give the straight lines I seek.

Is there a proper way to calculate such a point?

[image]

**EDIT:** For the figure above there are two possible solutions to connect $P_0$ to $P_1$ with two straight lines (i.e. horizontal or vertical). Either we go east then south; or south then east. *Following the curve* means the later solution is the one I am seeking because it somewhat follows the parabola.

[image]

I could say point $C$ is farthest from the focal point; but rather than this simple algorithm I would like to know if there's a more robust and mathematical definition for such point, such as Bezier Curves. You could this simply does not exist and that would be a valid solution.

[image]

**Brainstorming:** I've thought about using the tangent crossing (as in the comments below) but they don't yield the exact point I need as they depend on the slope. I've also thought about interpreting this parabola as part of a circle and computing the tangent crossings, but, intuitively, that seems to run into the same problem.

Comment: You say that point $C$ "follows the curve" : what do you mean by that ? Are you still thinking to curves more or less in the "Bezier family" ?

Comment: Exactly. In the example, both $C$ equal to $(3,1)$ or $(5,3)$ would form a straight line between($P0$, $C$, and $P1$). Only the first, however, would "follow the curve".

Comment: Therefore, why not taking tangents to the parabola in points $P_0,P_1$ and take their point of intersection (giving a classical Quadratic Bezier...)

Comment: I thought the tangents might yield non-horizontal/vertical lines for the parabola ([Wiki example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#/media/File:Quadratic_Beziers_in_string_art.svg)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, your question is not related to the parabola. You have two points, $P_0 =(x_0, y_0)$ and $P_1 = (x_0, y_0)$, and you want to construct a third point, $C = (C_x, C_y)$. The coordinates of $C$ are given by $C_x = \min(x_0, x_1)$ and $C_y = \min(y_0, y_1)$.

But perhaps I’m not correctly understanding what you mean by “follows the curve”. If you can give a better definition of that term, then the folks here can give you a better answer.

**Edit** (after you improved the question)
There are only two choices for the point $C$. I described one of them above. The right choice of $C$ depends on whether the parabola lies above or below the line $P_0P_1$. So, take the mid-point of the parabola (or some other convenient point lying on the parabola) and check whether it lies above or below the line $P_0P_1$.

If above, then $C_x = \max(x_0, x_1)$ and $C_y = \max(y_0, y_1)$.

If below, then $C_x = \min(x_0, x_1)$ and $C_y = \min(y_0, y_1)$.

Comment: We could define *following the curve* as third point $P_2$ whose triangle ($P_0, P_1, P_2$) would contain the curve within it. Intuitively, to connect two points $P_0$ and $P_1$ with straight lines only (horizontal/vertical) I have two options (see question edit). I want to find the option that follows the same directions as the curve.

Comment: That's what I've got implemented. I was looking for a direct approach, such as $C = formula(P_0, P_1, F, L)$. That doesn't exists though. Thanks for brainstorming.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to connect horizontal and vertical lines to $P_0$ and $P_1$,
you have only two choices of where to place the point $C.$

All of the points on the parabolic arc from $P_0$ to $P_1$ will lie on the same side of the line $P_0P_1.$

Choose any point on the arc. Determine which side of the line it lies on.
Choose the candidate for point $C$ that lies on the same side of the line.